# Open a dropdown menu, clicking somewhere else on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to open this dropdown select, not by clicking on it's position but on another `<span>`.

Here is the dropdown menu:

```
<div class="styled-select">
    <span id="camDurationSpanId" style="font-size:18px; position: absolute; top:8px; width:305px; height :42px;"></span>
    <select id="camDurationId" name="camDuration" style="margin:42px 0 0 5px; border: none" onmousedown="{this.size=this.options.length;} " onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
        <option value="0">All Duration</option>
        <option value="1">Last Month</option>
        <option value="2">Last Two Weeks</option>
        <option value="3">Last Week</option>
        <option value="4">Custom</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I want to open the dropdown menu by clicking over `<span id="camDurationSpanId">` and also, I want to put the selected option into this span.

Here is my javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#camDurationSpanId').click(function() {
        $('#camDurationId'). //don't know what to write here

    });
});
```

is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
  $(function () {
             $('#camDurationSpanId').click(function () {
                    $('#camDurationId').attr('size',5);
                });
            });
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/o7zn8f8h/

Comment: Thanks, worked ! but can you also suggest any solution to change "abrir select" to the selected option as well? I am trying to use document.getElementById('camDurationSpanId').innerHTML = .......

Comment: @reshad You can use `$('#camDurationSpanId').text('-------');`  for example : https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/o7zn8f8h/2/

Answer (score 1):

In order to programatically open a `select` box you need to trigger a `mousedown` event:

```
$('#camDurationId').trigger('mousedown');
```

[Here's a demo](https://jsbin.com/xadisapowe/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but is it possible also to change Open to the selected option, in your code, I mean when I select Custom, Open update to Custom? and also, how can I disable the original dropdown. sorry for so many questions in one comment

Comment: @reshad I think it would be a lot better if you used radio buttons instead of a dropdown, judging by the use-case you are describing.

Comment: @stackErr unfortunately I can't, I am ought to use select options